# Ask for suggestion: data type for parsing stringified fractional numbers

Tags: c++, c, parsing, configuration, embedded-systems

I am the author of [a C library](https://madmurphy.github.io/libconfini) for parsing INI files. So far I have delegated the task of parsing values as numbers to the standard `atoi()` family of functions. However I think time has come that I provide my specific functions for parsing numbers, since in INI files a number can be notated in octal, hexadecimal, etc., and there are a few more things in which I would like to specialize my own code.

Everything good so far. I have written two functions that are nearly-identical except for the data type. One parses integers, the other one parses fractional numbers. I have no doubts that the one that parses integers should return an `intmax_t` type. But what about the one that parses fractional numbers? Should that return a `double` or a `long double`?

Mine is a very general purpose library, it can be used in all kind of contexts, from embedded systems to desktop applications, and the INI files can be of all kinds. Whatever I choose now I will have to stick to it for a while, since changing the data type will break the binary compatibility.

So the question is: `double` or `long double` for parsing fractional INI values?

Comment: Having a look into the lib's documentation, it seems it provides already `ini_get_int()` for `int` values, `ini_get_lint()` for `long int` values and `ini_get_double()` for `double` values, Why don't you consequently add another function `ini_get_ldouble()` in case someone requires it?

Comment: Hi Doc. These are all the old functions that rely on the `atoi()`, `atof()`, etc. function family. My current intention is to deprecate those and provide two novel functions, one that returns an `intmax_t` and one that returns a `long double`. These two new functions will have much more power than the previous ones. For example they will be able to parse hexadecimal (e.g. `0xfe214`), octal (e.g. `01401`) and binary (e.g. `0b11001`) numbers, there will be an `error` object for the overflow/underflow cases, and they will have a few more additional skills.

Comment: Do the old functions cause any real issues, or are you just deprecating those older functions because they are old?

Comment: Well, there are a couple of critiques that can be raised. First, they are not functions, but function pointers to the C standard `atoi()`, `atol()`, `atoll()` and `atof()`. And as the latter belong to the C Standard Library there is really no need that I provide aliases. The second critique is that my library has generally developed the ability to work with raw INI strings without the need to parse them (namely removing quotes and unescaping). I would like that my number parsing functions be able to do the same. Third, as I said I would like to be able to parse hexadecimals and other bases.

Comment: Who is currently using your library? How does its user base look like? Can you talk to them and ask them what they require or prefer? I would try to listen to them and design the library towards their needs, not towards the ideas of some strangers from the internet who never used your lib.

Comment: Good question, Doc. I don't know. Judging from the daily clones (15-20) someone is. I suspect that it has some popularity among embedded systems programmers – but I can be wrong. I do have a direction in mind for my library independently of everything (and this is part of it). But some other parts of my direction will take more time.

Comment: Well, I would heavily recommend to get some feedback by your lib's users - only they can tell you what they really need.

Comment: That is a always wise suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `double` nor `long double` are suitable for expressing fractional numbers. They are for *floating point* numbers, not fractional numbers.

You should use a fractional number data type, something like this:

```c
struct fraction {
    intmax_t  numerator;
    uintmax_t denominator;
};
```

Instead of `intmax_t` / `uintmax_t`, you should probably use an arbitrary sized integer type.

Comment: Strictly speaking you are right, Jörg. But they are only INI files, wouldn't implementing a true `ratio` data type as in your example be too much in this case? I want a floating point data type, I just cannot choose which one.

Comment: It really depends on what you'll be doing with the numbers. Since you provide a library and are not the principal user, it would be best if you would provide users with options. Double versus long double would probably not make an important difference, but decimal fractions are sufficiently different that providing an option to read a configuration value as a decimal fraction makes sense.

Comment: Decimal fractions are an idea, and it is always possible to expand the library to provide this functionality. However the ability to parse a string as a floating point data type is really a must in this context. The two things do not exclude each other. But going back to my question (which is specific to when I want to return a floating poing type), which one would be the optimal solution according to you between a `double` and a `long double` in a general purpose library? I would opt for the `long double`, since it is always possible to reduce the precision required, but not the opposite.

Comment: I am partially changing my mind and moving towards arbitrary size numbers together with integers and floating point types. I am rewriting my code in that direction. Thank you guys for helping me clear my mind.